# I want to change the image based on my JSON response

Tags: android, json, api, weather-api, openweathermap

This is the screenshot of the app, I am making a weather app using open-weather-map API, Like if the response is sunny I want to show a sunny weather image from my drawable folder. I have also searched this question but didn't find the answer.

[image]

Comment: I think you required some kind of static mapping based on json response string to show image based on it.

Comment: After getting the json response, use switch case and update the image based on the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);   

String request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new 
Response.Listener<String>() 
{
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");

                String re = "";

                wlist=new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
                {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        re = jsonObject1.getString("re");

                        if(re.equals("sunny")
                        {
                           imageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunnyImage);

                        }

                        Model m = new Model(re);
                        userlist.add(user);
                }

                // Initialize adapter
                wlist.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
                //set adapter on your view
```

Answer (score 0):

**`You can try this function`**:-

```
private Drawable getDrawable(String source)
    {
        Drawable drawable;
        int sourceId =
                getApplicationContext()
                        .getResources()
                        .getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getPackageName());

        drawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(dourceId);

        drawable.setBounds(0,0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return drawable;
    }
```

**`function implementation`**:-

```
/*If you can get the JSON response same as the name of the image or set the name of the image as per your response this will work very efficiently*/

 imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable("sunny"));//this will return a drawable whose name is sunny
```

Do comment if any problem.